# How to Write Python array into a Single Excel Spread Sheet Cell

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am trying to write following array into an Excel spreadsheet cell using Python:

```
array = [ [a1,a2,a3], [a4,a5,a6], [a7,a8,a9], [a10, a11, a12, a13, a14]]
```

this is the code I am using right now:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

array = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
         ['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
         ['a7', 'a8', 'a9'],
         ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']]

row = 0

for col, data in enumerate(array):
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

This is the Output I am getting:

[image: This is the output im getting]

I want it to print it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `join()` and `set_text_wrap()`

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#workbook-add-format
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_text_wrap()
cell_format.set_align('vcenter')

array = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
         ['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
         ['a7', 'a8', 'a9'],
         ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']]

row = 0

for col, data in enumerate(array):
    worksheet.write(row, col, '\n'.join(data), cell_format)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: thank you @User863 if u dont mind what can i do to make the list print from the beginning in the cell

Comment: remove the line `set_align('vcenter')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a `"\n"` to store them all in a single cell.

Try to put something like this:

```py
array = ['\n'.join(i) for i in array]
```